# C++: Trouble grasping std::next_permutation and std::prev_permutation work

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, permutation

EDIT: Sorry, this turned out just to be my mistake in initializing in the code below.

```
const int kDigits = 7;
std::vector<int> number(kDigits);
for (int i = kDigits - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    number[i] = i + 1;
}
```

The vector `number` is initialized to `7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1`.
My goal is to generate the permutations in decreasing order:
`7654321
7654312
7654231
7654213
7654132`

This code **works**:

```
do {
...
}
while (std::prev_permutation(number.rbegin(), number.rend()));
```

However, I'm not understanding why. Since `7654321` is the largest lexicographical permutation, shouldn't `while (std::prev_permutation(number.begin(), number.end()));` (no reverse iterators) generate it correctly, since it would generate the **previous** permutation in order? However, this returns false on the first try, even though it should generate the "lower permutation."

Also, in the code shown above, since it uses reverse iterators, my mind interprets it as finding the previous permutation of `1234567` (`7654321` backwards), which seems to me should have none.

Thanks so much for the help in advance! I look forward to figuring out what I misinterpreted / what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector `number` is initialized to `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`, not `7,6,5,4,3,2,1`. That's why your code works.

If you want it initialized to `7,6,5,4,3,2,1`, you need to fix the initialization routine.

Answer (score 0):

The first permutation, by definition, has no previous permutation in forward order. Otherwise it wouldn't be first. That's why you need `rbegin` to get the "first" permutation for a reverse iterator (which is the last permutation).

Comment: Hmm, but isn't 7654321 considered the last permutation, so there would be no next permutation but there would be a previous permutation? For example, the sample code here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/prev_permutation/ shows the output as exactly how I expected -- 321, 312, 231, 213

Comment: That code does not pass an iterator to the constructor like yours does. I'm not sure what you think the similarity is between your code and theirs. You take the first entry in normal order (through `begin`) and then try to find a previous one (through `prev_permutation`, which can't work. They don't do that at all, they pass a range to the constructor, not an iterator.